# Representation theories between Lie algebra and its 1-dim central extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let the ground field is $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra. Assume that we have the following central extension 
$$ 0\rightarrow L \rightarrow  E \rightarrow  \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow  0.$$
Namely, $L$ is a one-dimensional Lie algebra, $E$ is  a Lie  algebra, and the image of $L$ lies in the center of $E$. What is the relation between category of $E$-modules and that $\mathfrak{g}$-modules ? Can we obtain one's information from another? Thanks!

Comment: $\mathfrak{g}$-modules are $E$-modules on which $L$ acts trivially. On irreducible representations $L$ acts by a scalar by Schur's lemma, and sometimes this scalar is $0$; then you get irreducibles of $\mathfrak{g}$. Otherwise you get projective irreducibles of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Understanding representations of $E$ from those of $\mathfrak{g}$ is far from clear. For instance, Ado's theorem is hard to prove: it says that every finite-dimensional complex Lie algebra $E$ has a faithful finite-dimensional representation. It is always obvious to find a representation whose kernel is the center $Z$: the adjoint representation, that is a faithful representation of $\mathfrak{g}=E/Z$. If deducing a faithful representation of $E$ was easy, we would have an easy proof of Ado's theorem, which is not the case (even when $Z$ is 1-dimensional).

Answer (score 1):

Let $p:L\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ be the morphism of the exact sequence and $V$ a $\mathfrak{g}$-module, it is defined by a morphism of Lie algebras $f:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow gl(V)$, $f\circ p$ endows $V$ with a structure of an $E$-module.

Conversely, consider  $U$  an $E$-module defined by $h:E\rightarrow gl(U)$. Let $x\in\mathfrak{g}$, $y,y'\in E, y\neq y'$ such that $p(y)=p(y')=x$, $h(y)=h(y')$ i.e $h(y-y')=0$, this implies that $h(L)=0$ since $y-y'\in L$ and $L$ is $1$-dimensional. If $h(L)=0$, we can define $\bar h:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow gl(U)$ by $\bar h(x)=h(y)$ where $p(y)=x$.